# Dealing with multiple touches for DPad and Shooting Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, sprite-kit, controls

I've been trying to implement touch controls into my game. I have a dpad and a reload button which I'm trying to change the opacity and figure out direction on the dpad (think I have this down), however you also have to tap to shoot. I'm struggling to figure out how to keep the touch on the dPad active whilst tapping elsewhere on the screen.

Currently I'm trying to store a dictionary with the keys being the UITouch and the value to be the object being tapped on, but I still can't get it work quite right.

Any advice would be lovely! Thanks.

P.S. Using Swift + Spritekit

Answer (score 1):

By default, once one gesture recognizer on a view “claims” the gesture, no others can recognize a gesture from that point on.

So you can split up the screen in 2 different views or you can keep the 1 view and do `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer,
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
         return true
    }
```

You can also specify

```
func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer,
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer || gestureRecognizer is UIRotationGestureRecognizer {
            return true
        }
  }
```

Comment: Cheers! I'll have to look into those.

Comment: If these don't work, feel free to comment and I'll see what I can find :) Feel free to upvote!